# Unit testing for exit() in C

Tags: c, exit, cunit

I'm using the CUnit framework for the way it displays the testing results. (I'm a programming & S.O. newbie so step by step answers really appreciated).

Is there any way I can use the same CUnit framework for when I'm testing for functions that I expect to exit()? It doesnt seem so to me, but I'm keen to ask anyway - it would display the pass/fail result along with my other CUnit tests so its ideal.

If not, I've been looking at other noob-friendly solutions (such as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904769/c-unit-testing-returning-from-a-stubbed-graceful-exit-routine)), but I cannot use GOTO/setjmp/longjmp. The solution also needs to be portable.

I'm using Mac & gcc command line to run this code.

**EDIT**
One of the suggested solutions is to use C Pre-Processor (CPP) Directive /["mocking"](https://locklessinc.com/articles/mocking/), which looks ideal? I have used the below code in my test.c file:

```
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {fprintf(stderr,"Fatal Error %s occurred in %s, line %d\n",PHRASE, FILE, LINE); exit(2);} 
#ifdef ERROR(PHRASE)
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("In test phase");} 
#endif 
#ifndef ERROR(PHRASE #define ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("Not In test phase");} 
#endif
```

Here is the error message that the terminal gives me:

```
test.c:30:9: warning: 'ERROR' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("In test phase");}
        ^
test.c:26:9: note: previous definition is here
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {fprintf(stderr,"Fatal Error %s occured in %s, lin...
        ^
test.c:32:14: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
      [-Wextra-tokens]
#ifndef ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("Not In test phase");}
```

Removing the (PHRASE) still gives the same errors.

**EDIT**
If helpful for anyone else, mocking using the #ifdef was the easiest way to solve this issue in the end. [This website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html) was helpful too.

Comment: I think it's extremely improbable. Instead of that you may try to use myExit() in your functions, which is, depending on whether you are in test mode (e.g. using some defines), calls exit() or does something else. I'm not sure what that "else" can be (since your program can rely on the fact that it stops after this).

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339094/cunit-mocking-libc-functions

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd ref](https://xkcd.com/1266/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so you know what to search for, what you want to do is "mock" the `exit()` call.  The basic idea is to choose a different implementation for the exit function, generally at compile time.  Frankly, C doesn't make this particularly easy, but there are some options with varying levels of portability and intrusiveness.

[This article](https://locklessinc.com/articles/mocking/) describes something that is pretty portable, but also fairly intrusive.  Basically, you use macros and/or function pointers to toggle back and forth, which means modifying your code a bit, but honestly it's not that big of a deal.

For something potentially less intrusive but also much less portable, [this article](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/) has a couple of ideas (I believe both would work on MacOS).  Here you get the linker to redirect the `exit()` call to another function, which you provide.  The good news is that it doesn't require any modifications to your code.  The bad news is that it requires you to gain the cooperation of the linker, and won't work everywhere (`LD_PRELOAD` won't work on Windows, and AFAIK `--wrap` requires GNU ld or something compatible).

Comment: The article you linked looks like what I need! I'm having some problems compiling through; I have the following code but it throws up the "Macro redefined" error"

#define ERROR {fprintf(stderr,"Fatal Error %s occured in %s, line %d\n",PHRASE, __FILE__, __LINE__); exit(2);}

#ifdef ERROR
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("In test phase");}
#endif
#ifndef ERROR
#define ERROR(PHRASE) {printf("Not In test phase");}
#endif

Comment: Can you post your code in the question? Then we can tell you what to tweak to get it working...

Comment: ifdef/ifndef shouldn't have the parameter lists.  For example, `#ifdef ERROR` not `#ifdef ERROR(PHRASE)`.

Answer (score 0):

One aspect that might be considered if there are issues/increased effort with regards to testing is if there's any scope to change the program being tested in some way that would help with testing without significantly increasing the complexity of the code.

In this case, is there scope to replace the calls to exit() with error return codes  from functions, such that the callers can do things such as tidy up, or log state, before actually exiting?  If so, this both simplifies testing and is likely to simplify fault-finding when the code is actually used in release/production, as it can be quite tricky to work out why a program just ups and dies on you, especially if the code is tucked away in a library function!

Comment: Agreed, in this case I had the exit() function throwing up a unique error code to stdout depending on which function failed. However I see this isn't ok in normal use cases so won't be doing it again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something non-intrusive, you can run the function under test as a separate process. You start this with `CreateProcess` (Windows) or `fork` (and possibly `execv` on Max and Linux. Your test code then use `wait` to test the exit code and pass if the created process exits correctly.